# why do the Google api examples have ;

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

for instance this is from the places documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/query

an example URL is called here:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/queryautocomplete/xml?&key;=AddYourOwnKeyHere&input;=pizza+near+sydne

but to make this work I must remove the ;'s that exist there...

is this just broken example code? or did I miss something about why Google is doing this?

Comment: Which semicolon where?

Comment: after key; after input;

Comment: It's obviously a typo in their documentation(must be new, I've never seen them before)

Comment: I've sent a [bug-report](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7665)